# The correct way to calculate MIPs of a function on a microcontroller

Tags: c

I want to calculate MIPs of a function on a microcontroller. Here is how I do it.
1. keil setting. Use Simulator and Xtal = 25MHz
[image]

[image]

2. Run simulator in debug mode.
   [image]
   As you can see, it takes 200ms to run fun() once.
   200ms(0.2s) * 25MHz = 5M. Does it mean that running `fun()` takes 5MIPs?
   One thing to note that the MIPs of `fun()` is independent of platform or crystal's oscillation frequency.
   Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code to review? Please stick to the [topic of this forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)/choose the right forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, **MIPS** means **M**ega **I**nstructions **P**er **S**econd.
So the formula would be

`CHIP_MIPS = number_of_mega_instructions / number_of_seconds`.

If your chip is running at 25 MHz, it means that it performs 25 mega instructions per seconds, so knowing the number of seconds and the CHIP_MIPS, the formula would be

`number_of_seconds * CHIP_MIPS = number_of_mega_instructions`

So `fun` needs 5 Mega Intructions

Comment: After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678771/how-to-calculate-mips-for-an-algorithm-for-arm-processor)  and your answer, I think you are correct. `fun` needs 5 Mega Instructions not 5 MIPs.

Comment: That right, sometimes even I say (improperly) I use 5 MIPS on my 25 budget, but it's not correct... and thanks for the link :-)

Comment: The question is blatantly off-topic: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Sorry @greybeard, it was my first answering attempt. I though questions about [good practices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) were on-topic. I'll be more careful next time.